# Are questions about the validity of studies on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

We have quite a lot of questions tagged [reference-request](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request); with 92 questions at the time of writing, it's one of our most popular tags. However, not every study that is cited in an answer to such questions is equally valid.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(statistics)#Test_validity) introduces the concept of **validity** as follows:

> Validity of an assessment is the degree to which it measures what it is supposed to measure.

It is to be distinguished from **reliability** (continuing from the previous quote):

> This is not the same as reliability, which is the extent to which a measurement gives results that are very consistent. Within validity, the measurement does not always have to be similar, as it does in reliability. However, just because a measure is reliable, it is not necessarily valid. E.g. a scale that is 5 pounds off is reliable but not valid.

Since we have so many questions that ask for answers backed up by studies, I would like to know if **questions asking about the validity of a specific study on language learning or teaching** would also be on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

If the question questions the scientific methodology of the study, that would probably not belong here, as that would be a question about the scientific method/research techniques/etc. possibly belonging on a site like Academia.

Otherwise, if the question asks about whether certain assertions in a study are backed up by other studies, for example, given the assertions or studies still pertain to language acquisition, those questions should still be on-topic.